# Cannot open shared folder under Debian (VirtualBox)

Tags: debian, virtualbox, file-sharing

There is a virtual machine under Debian 7.1.0 Wheezy i386 (guest). Host is Linux Mint 12.
The shared folder is set up with auto-mount, but it doesn't appear in `/media` directory, as said in the user manual. There are no analogous problems in Linux Mint 13 (another guest), the folder appears normally in `/media`.
I have installed `build-essential` and `module-assistant` and ran `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` from VBoxGuestAdditions but nothing is changed.

Comment: maybe run `mount` with no arguments to see if it mounted somewhere else?

Comment: The folder has a name 'withdeb', there is nothing similar in output